# How to check if blobstore file is readable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

How to check if [blobstore file used for writing](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview?hl=pl#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) was finalized and is ready for reading?

Am I to try to open the file and catch `FinalizationError`, try to `get_blob_key` or is there a `files.is_readable(blobstore_file_name)` method?

UPDATE:

I seem to wrote a confusing question, so I'll paint a background picture.

I am generating a file using [file api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview?hl=pl#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) with multiple background task's. This file is not readable until it is finalized.

I want to show a list of files being generated and show a download link for each when they're ready.

Adding boolean property "finalized" to an entity referencing these files just to indicate that the background process has finished, sounds silly.

And there are other cases where I would like to check the state of the file, without relaying on myself storing an indicator for each and every finalized file.

Comment: are you make sure that the file stores in the blobstore using admin console, so you can get the blobkey?

Comment: I do not want to do it manually, I am looking for a sanctioned method of determining if a file that have been used for writing is finalized and now ready for reading.

Comment: :you can get the key,if you can get it correctly(or download your stored file into your machine)for example, to check that it's stored correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `FinalizationError` can be thrown only during call to `finalize()`, so most probably you won't be able to get it while trying to `open()` a file.

After you finished writing your file, you may call `finalize()` or use `close(finalize=True)`:

```
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write(file_data)
    f.close(finalize=True)
```

and your file should be available for reading right after that.

Please, tell us if you get any problems using this approach.

Comment: Yo're not answering my question ;P I do not want to close/finalize a file. I what to check if it is already **closed and ready for reading**